# Implementing observer pattern with C# MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Simple concept. This is for a homework assignment, we are asked to use ASP.NET to make an application using a database. I am planning to make a TTT (tick-tac-toe) webpage where users can create games, join each other games, and have their W/L records saved in a database. This will be using MVC.

I've worked with MVC before and am comfortable building the application up. The question I have is implementing the **Observer pattern** in this so each user has a most-recent copy of the game on their screen (view).

I'm currently researching ways on how to approach this. I can always make a Javascript function on the view that requests the most recent copy of the game from the server every x seconds, such that both players always have an updated copy of the game. This would in fact solve the problem, but not correctly implement the Observer pattern. What would be ideal if the views subscribed to the model, if the model ever changed (through a controller action), the model could send an update through the controller to the views. This second approach sounds a bit wishy-washy and I'm reluctant to try it unless its the right way of going about implementing the Observer pattern.

What IS the correct approach to implement the Observer pattern? If you've used it before, how did you do it?

Comment: You're not going to be able to "push" updates to the client from the server because of the nature of the HTTP protocol. Your Javascript idea sounds like the most reasonable solution. To avoid needlessly reloading the game on the client, maybe a simple AJAX request checking if there is a newer version can be made. If there is, then an AJAX request can be made to grab the entire updated game.

Comment: Sounds like [SignalR](http://signalr.net/) would be appropriate. You can push notification from the server to one or more observers from the server in real time to the browser.

Comment: @itsme86 depending on what homework is about something like SignalR may be the answer.

Comment: You're right. SignalR would be a good solution.

Comment: yep, this is the exact scenario signalR was meant to handle.  It's just pub/sub though.  Just about any pub sub system will do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't copy this and I don't condone cheating if you do.

But [here](http://signalr-tictactoe.azurewebsites.net/) is a decent example of what I think your trying to do.

https://github.com/fekberg/Tic-Tac-Toe

Comment: Thank you for finding this, I won't copy what's there, but it is a good resource!

Comment: No problem at all I would suggest in future splitting your questions slightly but don't worry :)

Comment: How might you split the question? I feel as everything is self-contained as one

Comment: Actually you're probably ok :)